# Hyundai Getz - A/C (interior) blower doesn't turn off

Tags: electrical, ac, hyundai

**Problem solved:** It was a bad ignition switch. I replaced the switch and everything works fine.

Seems like the root cause was moisture + [this horrendous solder job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdWxJ.jpg).

---

Has anyone come across something similar before? Recently, I noticed that the A/C blower motor in my Getz was not turning off when I shut the car down. This happens around 50% of the time when I turn the car off, sometimes turning the electrics back on and off fixes the problem.

I've replaced the blower motor relay but that did not help. When I put the new relay in, it clicked and turned the blower on right away. The blower itself works fine, its different power levels are functional and I can turn if off manually.

Edit: My Getz is a 2006 model. The blower motor turns off after some time, I haven't measured but it's more than a minute or so. I've owned this car for several years, so I'm hesitant to believe this is a "feature" unless it is somehow triggered by the age/wear of the car. The ignition switch has some slack, as you would expect from a car with 220k on the odometer.

Edit 2: The problem seems to have stopped, or at lease become much more rare. Nonetheless I'll add my research below:

After scouring the internet, I've sound some semblance of an electrical diagram. It seems that the blower  is entirely controlled by a rotary switch (the one in the dash), which is powered by the blower relay, which receives its on signal from the ignition switch.

What's perplexing is how ONLY the blower would stay on, and no other electrical parts. If the ignition switch was broken, the problem should have been much broader, right?

[image]

The relay then only receives power when the ignition switch is turned to ON:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't replace the resistor. That won't help. It's just passing the current it receives to control blower speed. The problem is that it IS still getting power. Inspect the switch that controls the relay.

Comment: It's not because resistors don't open and close. It's a solid state component (really, it's a series of resistors) that has current passed through it.

Comment: It indeed is not possible that there's a problem with the resistors.  Instead, there's a problem with the control voltage which turns on everything when ignition is turned on. I'd say there's a defect in the ignition lock.

Comment: What year model? How long does it stay running? Does it cut off after 30 or 45 seconds?

Comment: Please provide the year of the car.  And one other question does this stay running no matter which fan speed is set?

Comment: How old is the car? How the ignition switch feels like? Is it firm or soft and slacken?

Comment: According to wiring diagrams the blower on high uses a different path for power then on the lower speeds, does the same issue occur  in all speeds?

Comment: The blower works 100% the same as it does when the car is on, I can set its power level normally or turn it off completely with the rotary switch.

Comment: @justinm410 - While I don't think it's the case here, it can happen in some vehicles where when the resistor pack fails, the fan will turn on high and not shut off with ignition cut off. If you have any doubts, look up auto-temp resistor packs for Chevrolet vehicles in the mid-2000's (RPO: CJ2 in my Silverado). I just replaced mine this weekend for this very problem. Chevy in their infinite wisdom provided an always on power supply to the resistor pack ... argh.

Comment: @Paulster2. I'm still a skeptic seeing as the recall includes the wiring harness or the resistor circuit contains something other than resistors. Resistors just don't "fuse". American cars, though. Smh.

Comment: The resistor pack (according to Hyundai diagrams) is isolated once the switch is in off or high fan positions.  It is no longer part of the circuit.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's not the radiator fan?

Comment: I updated my answer, please see below

Answer (score 5):

Some vehicles let the blower motor run 15 to 30 seconds after the vehicle is turned off. Others turn it back on 5 to 15 minutes after the vehicle has been turned off. This is done to blow off the condensation that builds up on the evaporator to prevent mildew from building up on the evaporator and causing a musty smell when the HVAC is used. So this may be a normal function or the vehicle.

Inside the circle of the picture below is where you will likely find your answer. The "PTC Heater Module" indicated on the wiring diagram. The SD971-3 is likely the page number the rest of the wiring diagram can be found, on that page you will see the same B arrow with the wire coming out of the point indicating it comes from this page. I don't know what that module does exactly but it's likely written in the circuit description of the service manual. It could be there in part to turn on the blower motor after the ignition turns off for the reasons I stated above, or it could have some other function and could be faulting and grounding the relay when it shouldn't be.

[image]

Some have described this as a "feature" of the vehicle. It's not really a feature in the sense of power windows, or CD player. It's more of an operating characteristic of the vehicle, like the EGR valve for example so don't expect it to be listed in the owners manual.

The next time it does it turn off the blower motor by the blower motor switch and see if the blower immediately stops. Then comment on this answer with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a climate control unit?

There are 2 kinds of resistors which could cause this problem:

1. The one that measures the inside temperature(temperature sensor)
2. The one that gives the blower sufficient power to run at a certain speed.

The first one could result into weird behavior like unwanted temperature or the blower keeps running on low or full speed.

The second one result into a not working blower or running at full speed.

Answer (score 0):

There are no kind of "resistors" which can cause this problem.

I checked Hyundai Getz Owner's Manuals from 2006.  There is absolutely no mention whatsoever of this behavior as a "feature".  In addition, this is a "super-mini" baseline car, that probably would not have the mildew prevention features (like poster MoveMoreComments metioned) that a BMW or Mercedes migtht have.

However, I cannot find an electrical diagram for this vehicle.  With that, I could directly identify the problem.  This is not a model available in the US to my knowledge, which severely limits my resources.

And THEN, I say *whatever*, and pick the Hyundai Accent for 2006, which I have complete information for, and is the entry-level vehicle for the US market.

And I discover some interesting stuff:

[image: HVAC Elec Diagram 1 2006 Accent]

And even more importantly, this:

[image]

Note that "Active In-car Humidity Sensor".  And note that the blower and HVAC control are so-called "*Hot at All Times*"  So even additionally moreso importanter:

[image]

Is this what your Getz does?  I would have sworn *NO*, but there is ample evidence to suggest it might... even on an entry-level vehicle.  Note that a variety of sensors would contribute to this phenomena, so the behavior would not be consistent from day-to-day, temperature-to-temperature, season-to-season, etc.

So...  I feel like I've done a *really* good job of *NOT* actually answering your question...